# DROP CONTRACT [contract_name] in SQL server broker taking too much time

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

DROP CONTRACT [contract_name]  in SQL server broker taking time and execution not getting finished. I disabled BROKER and tried, still the same issue. I'm working on SQL Server ManagementStudio v17.3

```
DROP CONTRACT [//Audit/Contract] ;
```

Comment: I believe that dropping a contract will end any conversations currently using that contract. Do you have any? Check sys.conversation_endpoints.

Comment: @BenThul -  sys.conversation_endpoints have data. How can we check that this contract (//Audit/Contract) has a conversation?

Comment: Join it back to sys.service_contracts on service_contract_id

Comment: ya. That contract has some conversations. So before delete CONTRACT, we have to END those conversations. Is it? If so How can we do that?
( I wish to delete the contract without modifying the service)

Comment: Yep. I'd start there. Under normal conditions, you should be ending your conversations naturally (i.e. begin conversation, send some messages back and forth, end conversation). That said, there are some specific reason *not* to (which, in the interest of full disclosure, I do in my environment). All of that is to say that you should probably also investigate why you have so many open conversations in addition to ending them.